# Unpacking List of Tuples of List(s)

Tags: python, list, tuples, list-comprehension

I have a list of tuples where one of the elements in the tuple is a list.

```
example = [([0, 1, 2], 3, 4), ([5, 6, 7], 8, 9)]
```

I'd like to end up with just a list of tuples

```
output = [(0, 1, 2, 3, 4), (5, 6, 7, 8, 9)]
```

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18500541/how-to-flatten-a-tuple-in-python) seems to address the issue with tuples but I am concerned as my use case has many more elements in the inner list and

```
[(a, b, c, d, e) for [a, b, c], d, e in example]
```

seems tedious.  Is there a better way to write this?

Comment: Do all your tuples match the `([a, b, c], d, e)` pattern exactly ?

Comment: Yes.  The actual list i have has 100 elements but the 100 is uniform and it will always have 2 elements on the outside.

Comment: If all the tuples in the list match the pattern of ([a, b, c], d, e), then your code is pythonic and doesn't seem tedious.

Comment: Could the position of the list in the tuple change or is it fixed ?

Comment: the list in the tuple will always be the zeroth

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tuples can be concatenated with `+` like lists.  So, you can do:

```
>>> example = [([0, 1, 2], 3, 4), ([5, 6, 7], 8, 9)]
>>> [tuple(x[0]) + x[1:] for x in example]
[(0, 1, 2, 3, 4), (5, 6, 7, 8, 9)]
```

Note that this works in both Python 2.x and 3.x.

Answer (score 4):

In Python3 you could also do:

```
[tuple(i+j) for i, *j in x]
```

if you don't want to spell out each part of your input

Comment: I love it ! Care to explain what exactly happens for the poor fellas like me still stuck with Python 2.x ?

Comment: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` on the `*j` happens for Python2.x.

Answer (score 2):

If writing a function is an option:

```
from itertools import chain

def to_iterable(x):
    try:
        return iter(x)
    except TypeError:
        return x,

example = [([0, 1, 2], 3, 4), ([5, 6, 7], 8, 9)]
output = [tuple(chain(*map(to_iterable, item))) for item in example]
```

Which gives:

```
print(output)
[(0, 1, 2, 3, 4), (5, 6, 7, 8, 9)]
```

It's way more verbose than the other solutions, but has the neat advantage of working no matter the position or number of lists in the inner tuples. Depending on your requirements this might be overkill or a good solution.