# Python Convert Tuple of List to List

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have the following stored in the variable `resultset`:
(['James Taylor'], ['Sarah Jarosz'], ['Crooked Still'])

I would like to rewrite this as a list, i.e. ['James Taylor', 'Sarah Jarosz', 'Crooked Still' ].

How would I go about this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making a flat list out of list of lists in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python). I know your case has a tuple instead of a list, but the solutions listed there apply. There are plenty of other similar questions too like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18500541/how-to-flatten-a-tuple-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case this is not in fact a duplicate:

```
resultset = (['James Taylor'], ['Sarah Jarosz'], ['Crooked Still'])
new_list = [i[0] for i in resultset]
print new_list
```

['James Taylor', 'Sarah Jarosz', 'Crooked Still']

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use:

```
l = (['James Taylor'], ['Sarah Jarosz'], ['Crooked Still']) 
new_l = [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]
```